# How I can disable here properly hover effect on element?

Tags: wordpress

I
I'm beginer. I have a problem with disabling hover effect on some element im im right. When i disable hover effect on element, my button don't work. Pls help me with that.The hover effect is done on clas - category-filter-default. Check the image also pls.

https://rocket-mama.com/

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yN71.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

put this css and then check

```
.opal-category-subs .category-filter-default .filter-img:before {
    content: "";
    position: unset; 
    transition: none !important;
}
.opal-category-subs .category-filter-default:hover {
    transition: none !important;
    background: none !important;
    border: none  !important;
}
.opal-category-subs .category-filter-default:hover h4 {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it helped alot, now i see, that a caption showing number of products is still visible, but i'll try to change it. you saved my life :D i was trying several options and it didn't work.

Comment: `.opal-category-subs .category-filter-default:hover small {
    display: none;
}` use it for remove no of products

Comment: Thank you, also works really great, I need to learn alot still :D

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation to upvote, but really tried.